# AutoMapper configuration properties by order between (anonymous type and a dynamic)

Tags: c#, json.net, automapper

I'm using [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library in order to create a `List<dynamic>` objects:

```
List<dynamic> dynamics = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(response.Content);
```

I want to achieve to parse each `dynamic` object to an `AnonymousType`. So in order to get that, I'm using [dynamic feature of AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping).

The problem is this AutoMapper feature is based on a PropertyName-based convention. So each property with the same name is mapped.

The problem I've suddently come up is a json key `comment` might be like: `Comment`, `COMMENT`, `CoMMeNt`, and so on. So, if AnonymousType has a property `comment`, AutoMapper won't map this. So, `anonymous.comment is not equals to dynamic.CoMMeNt`.

Nevertheless, Anonymous type might have a absolutly different named properties. So, `anonymous.field is not equals to dynamic.comment`.

I would like to map each property by order. So, first property on anotnymous type is mapped to the dynamic's first one.

How could I get that?

Answer (score 0):

Create your a new base type, derived from `DynamicObject` that handles the naming convention you desire in the `TryGetMember` or similar methods. Then, when **AutoMapper** is calling into you object at runtime you can handle the naming issue:

```
public bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
{
    string name = binder.Name.ToLower();
    if (name == "comment") 
    {
      // save comment
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution. However, I'm not able to figure out how to handle with absolutly different property names (anonymous.field / dynamic.dleif).

Comment: For something like that you would need to keep a map of *common* mis-spellings and variations that you would want to fix up. My guess would be this list would not be comprehensive when started but expand over time.